# Regarding moving to new screen using fragment and textview

Tags: android

I am developing an application which involves various screen for tablet. On one side I have all the tabs like notification, messages and other using fragment. When any one click on any tabs it changes the other part of screen leaving tabs unaltered. Now problem is, when I click on a tab say notification there is a message showing that " you have 3 messages",(Which is written in text view), with messages as link to that screen which shows messages. How would i achieve that when any one click on message(written in text view), it should display screen with message. In simple word how to add a link to another screen using text view.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. My code for main activity is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends ActivityGroup
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);

    }


    public void onNotificationsClick(View view)
    {
        setFragment(new NotificationsFragment());
    }


    public void onWorkListClick(View view)
    {
        setFragment(new WorkListFragment());
    }

    public void setFragment(Fragment fragment)
    {
        FrameLayout framelayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_container);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(framelayout.getId(), fragment).commit();

    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you make your solution as a separate post and mark it as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.

I just added in fragment_home.xml, *tv_alert_info_note text view* I added

```
android:clickable="true" 
android:onClick="onMessageClick"
```

and like the same way added method "onMessageClick" in main activity class which is adding corresponding layout. that is

```
 public void onMessageClick(View view)
        {
            setFragment(new TestFragment());
        }
```

where TestFragment is fragment class.